# Error uploading .bmp file format - gets rejected

Tags: upload

I'm doing some testing on file uploads and discovered that the .bmp file format gets rejected even though defined in my config file as an allowed file extension.

**I have added the following to my config file:**

```
 'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'bmp, jpeg, tiff, pdf, cdr, gbr, gtl, dxf, dwg',
 'allowedFileExtensions' => 'bmp, jpeg, tiff, pdf, cdr, gbr, gtl, dxf, dwg',
```

**This is the error I receive:**

The file “/private/var/tmp/php7Md2bj” does not appear to be an image.

/shop/craft/app/etc/image/Image.php(138)

```
138    throw new Exception(Craft::t('The file “{path}” does not appear to be an image.', array('path' => $path)));
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried 'turning it off and on again' - i.e. open the file in photoshop or similar and save-as ? (Just thinking out aloud)

Comment: Tried that - it does this to all .bmp files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably using [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), which doesn't support BMP files.

If you install  [Imagick](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) on your server, Craft will use it automatically and it supports a much wider range of file types, including BMP files.

Comment: We noticed that with Imagick enabled users can no longer download PDFs orders from the website. Have you come across this issue?