# Craft Commerce: Imagick stops PDF order downloads

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, pdf

We needed to use Imagick so that our users could upload `.bmp` files to Craft - this works fine, however we noticed this directly stops users downloading PDFs orders from the website and a server errors gets applied.

Has anyone had any similar issues or advice on how to remedy?

Here is our original issue with `.bmp` files: [Error uploading .bmp file format - gets rejected](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/15830/error-uploading-bmp-file-format-gets-rejected)

Comment: When you installed Imagick, did you uninstall GD?  Looks like dompdf (the library Commerce uses to generate PDF files) has an explicit requirement for GD: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/composer.json#L29

Comment: GD is installed and PDF downloads work fine when we disable Imagick. Somehow there is a conflict.

Comment: Maybe try updating your GD/Imagick versions? Just did a test locally with both installed and not have any issues, but they are pretty recent versions.

Comment: Hi Brad, we are still having issues with this. What versions are you running on just so we can compare our side?

Comment: Imagick Module 3.1.2, ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2015-07-06 and GD 2.1.0.